# Elementary OS 6 freezing

Tags: release-odin

I have recently installed Elementary OS 6.0 on an old machine (Dell Latitude E6400 with 8GB RAM and 256GB drive) and have been having a lot of problems with it freezing. Not having managed to track down the problem, I decided to start from scratch this morning but still have the problem.

After installing I updated the system packages using AppCenter, the only changes I had made were to region, language and connecting to a wifi router. I'd made no other manual changes when the first freeze happened. That was shortly after opening Epiphany. Other than the pointer which I could move around the screen using the trackpad, the system was totally unresponsive. I tried to open a TTY session but couldn't. After waiting for about 10 minutes I used the power button to shut down.

After booting again everything was fine for about a while. I installed LibreOffice from Flathub and when I opened Calc for the first time, the screen froze again. The symptoms were the same, other than moving the pointer nothing on the screen changed and I couldn't open a TTY session with the keyboard. As the clock at the top of the screen was also frozen I know that the machine was unresponsive for 17 minutes so was able narrow down the search for clues in the logs. This time the system came back by itself, but a 17 minute wait .

Do the entries in the syslog below show what the problem is? and where to start fixing it? I'm not sure which of the errors would cause the freeze.

````
Oct  1 14:25:48 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1137]: app-flatpak-org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264-4458.scope: Succeeded.
Oct  1 14:26:31 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1137]: Started app-flatpak-org.libreoffice.LibreOffice-4889.scope.
Oct  1 14:26:32 LatitudeE6400 soffice.bin[4938]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Oct  1 14:26:35 LatitudeE6400 kernel: [ 3047.286991] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: trapped read at 010108e000 on channel -1 [0fee0000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 00000002 [PAGE_NOT_PRESENT]
Oct  1 14:26:32 LatitudeE6400 soffice.bin[4938]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Oct  1 14:26:35 LatitudeE6400 soffice.bin[4953]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Oct  1 14:26:35 LatitudeE6400 soffice.bin[4953]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Oct  1 14:26:37 LatitudeE6400 gala[1400]: clutter_actor_add_effect_with_name: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Oct  1 14:26:37 LatitudeE6400 gala[1400]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (child)' failed
Oct  1 14:26:37 LatitudeE6400 gala[1400]: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
Oct  1 14:26:37 LatitudeE6400 gala[1400]: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
Oct  1 14:29:32 LatitudeE6400 PackageKit: daemon quit
Oct  1 14:29:32 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Oct  1 14:30:01 LatitudeE6400 CRON[4982]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Oct  1 14:30:46 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1137]: app-flatpak-org.gnome.Epiphany-3526.scope: Succeeded.
Oct  1 14:31:13 LatitudeE6400 systemd-timesyncd[760]: Initial synchronization to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c7]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Oct  1 14:32:22 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1]: flatpak-system-helper.service: Succeeded.
Oct  1 14:35:00 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Oct  1 14:35:00 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Oct  1 14:35:00 LatitudeE6400 anacron[4992]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-10-01
Oct  1 14:35:00 LatitudeE6400 anacron[4992]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Oct  1 14:40:07 LatitudeE6400 kernel: [ 3859.389546] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
Oct  1 14:43:26 LatitudeE6400 kernel: [ 4058.818536] [TTM] Buffer eviction failed
Oct  1 14:43:27 LatitudeE6400 kernel: [ 4059.009833] rfkill: input handler enabled
Oct  1 14:43:37 LatitudeE6400 kernel: [ 4069.956040] rfkill: input handler disabled
Oct  1 14:43:38 LatitudeE6400 gala.desktop[1400]: Window manager warning: last_focus_time (4070397) is greater than comparison timestamp (3086541).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Oct  1 14:43:40 LatitudeE6400 gala[1400]: meta_end_modal_for_plugin: assertion 'is_modal (display)' failed
Oct  1 14:43:49 LatitudeE6400 gala.desktop[1400]: Window manager warning: last_user_time (4081974) is greater than comparison timestamp (4081967).  This most likely represents a buggy client sending inaccurate timestamps in messages such as _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW.  Trying to work around...
Oct  1 14:43:49 LatitudeE6400 gala.desktop[1400]: Window manager warning: 0x540001c appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 4081974.  Working around...
Oct  1 14:43:50 LatitudeE6400 systemd[1137]: app-flatpak-org.libreoffice.LibreOffice-4889.scope: Succeeded.```
````

Comment: How old is this old computer? Can you [edit] your question to include the brand and model, as well as the amount of memory and storage that is in the device?

Comment: I've added a little more detail on the machine. The CPU is slightly earlier than recommended but it has plenty of disk space and memory, and runs Windows 7 without problems.

Comment: Your machine has a Core2Duo processor, which is going to struggle with the UI. You might want to try a lighter distro, such as Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, or Bodhi Linux 